# Why do some linux tools write to STDERR instead of STDOUT by default?

Tags: io-redirection

Why do some Linux utility programs send output for "normal" operation to STDERR instead of STDOUT?

For example, when I run the following command (in CentOS 7.3):

```
/usr/sbin/grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg 1> /dev/null ; echo $?
```

I see the output on the TTY even though the exit status is zero and there are no errors.

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-1ef39414718640fe9f6ec0f6d65fdc3e
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-1ef39414718640fe9f6ec0f6d65fdc3e.img
done
0
```

I've noticed a handful of other programs that do this as well. Wondering if there is some good explanation.

For reference, I need to call this this line in an RPM %post script and I'd like to redirect "normal" output to `/dev/null` and capture only true "error" type messages. This particular command does not offer a `-q quiet` switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grub2-mkconfig` normally writes the generated config file to
*stdout* so you can redirect it conveniently. Status information
is written to *stderr* since it would interfere with the
redirected output. When you use the `-o` argument instead, the
latter behavior stays the same, which it should for sake of
consistency:

```
# grub2-mkconfig >/tmp/grub.conf.a
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.15-200.fc22.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.8.15-200.fc22.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-b764638bab7b90d16d0510c14a429d80
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-b764638bab7b90d16d0510c14a429d80.img
Found Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two) on /dev/sda2
done
# grub2-mkconfig -o /tmp/grub.conf.b
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.15-200.fc22.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.8.15-200.fc22.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-b764638bab7b90d16d0510c14a429d80
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-b764638bab7b90d16d0510c14a429d80.img
Found Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two) on /dev/sda2
done
# diff -u /tmp/grub.conf.{a,b}
```